# Does libpcap always make a copy of the packet?

Tags: libpcap, packet-capture

I am writing monitoring program for a very high traffic network (HD videos are streamed through the network). Most packets are very large and I only want to watch the headers (IP and UDP/TCP only). Of course I want to avoid overhead of copying the entire data. Does libpcap necessarily give me a copy the whole packet? If yes, is there any library that matches my needs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There appear to be two questions here:

- the one in the title, which sounds as if it's asking whether libpcap copies the packet;
- the one in the body, asking whether it always copies the *entire* packet.

For the first question:

There's probably at least one copy done by any code using the mechanisms atop which libpcap runs in various OSes - a copy from the mbufs/skbuff/STREAMS buffers/whatever to the mechanism's buffer.  For Linux, when the tpacket mechanism is *not* being used, the skbuff *might* just be queued on the receive queue for the `PF_PACKET` socket libpcap is using.

There may be another copy - a copy from that buffer to userland; if libpcap is using a "zero-copy" mechanism, such as the Linux tpacket mechanism (which libpcap 1.0 and later use by default), the second copy doesn't happen.  It *will* happen if a zero-copy mechanism isn't being used.

However, if you're using `pcap_next()` or `pcap_next_ex()` on a Linux system and the tpacket mechanism is being used, a separate copy, from the memory-mapped buffer to a private buffer; that doesn't happen if you use `pcap_dispatch()` or `pcap_loop()`.

For the second question:

That's what the "snaplen" argument to `pcap_open_live()` and `pcap_set_snaplen()` is for - it lets you specify that no more than "snaplen" bytes of packet data should be captured, and that means that no more than that many bytes are copied.

Note that this length includes the link-layer headers, and that those can include "metadata" headers such as [radiotap](http://www.radiotap.org/) headers that you might get on 802.11 adapters.  This header might be variable-length (for example, on 802.11, the 802.11 header is variable-length, and, if you're getting radiotap headers, those are variable-length as well).

In addition, both IPv4 and TCP headers can have options, and IPv6 packets can have extension headers, so the length of IP and TCP headers can also be variable.

This means that you might have to determine a "worst case" snapshot length to use; there's no way to explicitly say "don't give me anything past the TCP/UDP header", you can only say "give me no more than N bytes".